# How can I disable cmake's Visual Studio macro which prompts the user to reload the solution when a CMakeLists.tx has changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

Because Visual Studio 2010 is broken and won't automatically reload a solution when it changed externally via CMake, the guys at kitware made this macro that prompts you to reload the whole solution instead of pressing reload for every project like Visual Studio does. This would be nice if it actually worked.

In VC 10 this macro is broken and further chokes the ide.  I have another solution for automatically reloading externally changed projects/solutions (the VSCommands add-in) and would want to disable cmake's macro of doing so. Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "disable" the CMake macro that runs to prompt for solution reloading, you could edit the macro labeled "DO NOT EDIT THIS MACRO"...

In Visual Studio, choose "Tools > Macros > Macros IDE..." from the menu, comment out the body of the "ReloadProjects" and "StopBuild" macros in the CMakeVSMacros2.Macros module, and then even when CMake calls those macros, they'll have no effect.

Perhaps you could do that, and also try the VS addin mentioned in this CMake bug report on the topic: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=11258#c27652

Comment: I use the  VSCommands addin but I needed to disable the cmake macro which was broken. I think that does the trick. Thanks!

Although good in general, the VSaddin fails to load newly added projects to the solution. It just reloads the modifications of existing projects :/

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i found in LLVM' CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Workaround for MSVS10 to avoid the Dialog Hell
# FIXME: This could be removed with future version of CMake.
if(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1600)
  set(LLVM_SLN_FILENAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LLVM.sln")
  if( EXISTS "${LLVM_SLN_FILENAME}" )
    file(APPEND "${LLVM_SLN_FILENAME}" "\n# This should be regenerated!\n")
  endif()
endif()
```

It seems, this code updates .sln file and forces Visual Studio to reload whole solution at once, instead of asking you about each project.

Comment: this looks like it just appends a new line with the comment "This should be regenerated" and then a new line feed.

Comment: Sorry, if it didn't help you. For me, it makes VS prompt me with "Reload solution?" dialog.

Comment: Working perfectly here with CMake 3.0.2.